# Copy elision (NRVO) with deleted copy and move constructors possible?

Tags: c++, nrvo

In the [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) it is said that

> The copy/move constructors need not be present or accessible in a
>   return statement, when the operand is a prvalue of the same class type
>   (ignoring cv-qualification) as the function return type:
>
> ```
> T f() {
>     return T();
> }
>
> f(); // only one call to default constructor of T
> ```

Am I understanding this right and in order to make the above example work, it is inevitable to have at least one copy or move constructor?

What I tried is the following:

```
class Player
{
  //...
  public:
    Player();
    Player(std::string name);
    Player& operator=(const Player&) = delete;
    Player& operator=(Player&& p) = delete;
    Player(const Player& origin) = delete;
    Player(Player&& p) = delete;

    Player getEmptyPlayer() const {
      return Player("Name");
    }
}

//in main:

Player p1("It's Me");
Player p2 = p1.getEmptyPlayer();
```

Why is this code compiling and working? To my understanding actually the method getEmptyPlayer() would need to call the copy constructor for copying the object when returning. Due to efficiency improvements by the compiler this is not the case but the copy elision (NRVO) comes to turn and directly constructs the object where it should be and does not make a copy. Nonetheless, the cppreference (see above) says that an accessible or present copy/move constructor needs to exist. So what is happening here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It says they need not be present. That is, they are not needed

Comment: I don't understand the question. The quote says *"copy/move constructors need not be present or accessible"*, so why *"inevitable to have at least one copy or move constructor"*? Also, this is RVO, not NRVO.

Comment: I can't believe it. I just can't read. What I omitted is the the not. Now I understand why people write it bold ...

Answer (score 1):

> Copy elision (NRVO) with deleted copy and move constructors possible?

No.

If there is a copy (or move), then the type must be copyable (or movable). Just because the copy (or move) could be optimised away does not make such program well-formed.

> Why is this code compiling and working?

Because there is no copy (nor move) involved (since C++17).

> To my understanding actually the method getEmptyPlayer() would need to call the copy constructor for copying the object when returning.

It does not since C++17.

It used to be needed before C++17 (and the call could be elided).

Comment: Do you know why it is ok if copy is deleted but move is not, when trying to copy? Like if I return a unique_ptr.

Comment: @pooya13 If you return an automatic variable, then you *are* moving.

Comment: Ok good to know thanks! I know it is off topic but what do you mean by "automatic" variable? (could you point me to a reference perhaps?)

Comment: @pooya13 I mean a variable with automatic storage duration. Look up "storage duration".

Comment: Still compiles when both copy/move constructors are deleted with `-std=c++11`. What happened? https://godbolt.org/z/jsdWvndP5

Comment: `What happened?` you directly value-initialized a return value. No copying/moving was involved. This is different from `return T()` which value initializes a temporary object (pre c++17) which is then used to copy initialize the return value (which is illformed due to deleted constructors). If you tried to initialize an object with the return value, the program would also be ill-formed: `T t = func();`

Answer (score 0):

The question absolute nonsense. The cite says "The copy/move constructors need **not** be present [...]".

I am terribly sorry for not reading correctly.